# WPF Listview search SQL table for data

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a SQL table that hosts the data which varies depending on day to day activity. I have a C# WPF application that I'm trying to set up to view this SQL data. How it works: You type in a last name of someone and click search then the listview will display the data based on SQL command.

Here is the XAML Code I have for the listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="searchedList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" Margin="10,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="555" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Server}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NameColumn}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="TimeA" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeAColumn}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="TimeB" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeBColumn}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="TimeC" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeCColumn}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="DateA" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateAColumn}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="DateB" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateBColumn}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Here is the C# portion of that code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("mysqlconnection");
            DataSet ds;
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            SqlCommandBuilder scb;
            DataTable dt;

            da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [NameColumn] LIKE '%'" + txtSearch.Text + "'%' OR [DateAColumn] LIKE '%'" + txtSearch.Text + "'%' OR [TimeAColumn] LIKE '" + txtSearch.Text + "' OR [TimeBColumn] LIKE '" + txtSearch.Text + "' OR [TimeCColumn] LIKE '" + txtSearch.Text + "'", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            dt = new DataTable();
            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            searchedList.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            con.Open();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

However when typing in a last name of someone that is definitely in the database, the Listview does not populate with needed data. I can't seem to find where I am going wrong, of course I'm still fairly new to WPF in C#. (This is a search function so it does need to be blank until searching for data.)

Comment: You should use parameter based query. Your single quotes are not correctly placed. Ex:  LIKE '%'" + txtSearch.Text + "'%' should have been  LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'"

Comment: @Anup Sharma very nice, now it is populating. If you provide the answer I will mark it as answered for everyone else. thanks a ton :)

Comment: Nice things to also do would be: do the querying on another thread using TPL (tasks, etc), also don't just eat up all the caught errors and do nothing about them, also use finally (from the try-catch) to ensure that your connection to the database is always closed even if there's an error. But hey, i'm pretty sure that the code above is probably for testing/learning purposes and not production code. :)

Comment: yes all for testing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on the comment, Here is the Answer:**

NOTE: You must use parameter based query, else you are inviting SQL-Injection attack.

Apart from this,

Wildcard Characters (%,_,etc) must be within the single quotes along with the values you are passing.

Hence, try this:

```
'%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'"
```

Instead of

```
'%'" + txtSearch.Text + "'%'
```